# Changing URL output of User Input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to build something simple here:

a user types into an input field a url eg. `http://sharepoint.com/human-resources/usa/Lists/testList/EditForm.aspx?ID=666&Source=http%3A%2F%sharepoint.com`

.. hits "submit", when the URL gets spit out as a link, changing into: `https://sharepointusa.com/en-us/human-resources/usa/Lists/testList/EditForm.aspx?ID=666&Source=http%3A%2F%sharepoint.com`

I've been trying unsuccessfully to just spit out the whole URL, losing parameters, so I need a new approach, what is an easy vanilla javascript to just replace http://sharepoint.com/ with https://sharepointusa.com/en-us/ and leave the rest of the URL?

thanks

EDIT: 2 great answers, thank you, I adapted the first answer to my original code, while I play around with the second answer to see how it compares!:

```
<a href="" id="link"></a><br>
<input type="text" id="userInput" value="Enter your text here"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="changeText2()" value="change text">
<script>
function changeText2()
{
  var input=document.getElementById('userInput').value;//gets the value entered by user
const updatedUrl = input.replace('http://sharepoint.com/', 'https://sharepointusa.com/en-us/');
    document.getElementById("link").href = updatedUrl;
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = updatedUrl;
    

}

</script>
```

Comment: sorry, i went to put the code in I was using - I got an answer right away so I just paste in the corrected code

Comment: You need to ask a clear question in your question. Don't put answers in there. If you haven't done so the question will be closed since it won't offer much value to the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a variable containing the full original url

```
const url = 'http://sharepoint.com/human-resources/usa/Lists/testList/EditForm.aspx?ID=666&Source=http%3A%2F%sharepoint.com';
```

then you can just do

```
const updatedUrl = url.replace('http://sharepoint.com/', 'https://sharepointusa.com/en-us/');
```

and updatedUrl will have what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

It1 got it right before me! anyways, this is a more advanced representation of how to change it directly from the input fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <input id="demo" value="http://sharepoint.com/human-resources/usa/Lists/testList/EditForm.aspx?ID=666&Source=http%3A%2F%sharepoint.com">
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
      var changed = str.replace("sharepoint", "sharepointusa");
      document.getElementById("demo").value = changed;
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```